# VS Code : Selecting js file to debug, without changing Launch Configuration

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I noticed that the debug mode in VS Code uses the launch.json "program" entry to decide which file to launch.

Is there any way to bypass this ? I would like to just like right-click and debug a specific file in my Node App. As of now, I have to go edit launch.json everytime I am debugging a new js file.

```
"configurations": [

        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\hello.js"
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

VS Code currently does not support debugging by right clicking on file. The closest alternative you can have is debugging the currently opened file, set your `program` property to `${file}` in your `launch.json`:

```
{
    // ...
    "program": "${file}"
}
```

See [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_variable-substitution) for a list of available variables you can use in `launch.json`